# Проверка наличия слова в строке

Tags: java, строки

Нужно написать алгоритм, который будет проверять наличие слова в слове.

```
public class Hello {

    int count;
    boolean result;

    public boolean contains(String origin, String sub) {
        char[] one = origin.toCharArray();
        char[] two = sub.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i <one.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <two.length; j++) {
                //проверяем символы на идентичность
                if (two[i+j] == one[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(count == two.length ) {
            String s = new String(two);
            result = origin.contains(s);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при проверке условия  `if (two[i+j] == one[j])` у меня постоянно выходит ошибка - выход за пределы массива. Не могу сам решить. Уже нет мыслей, как сделать.

Comment: Приведите пример слов `origin` и `sub`.

Comment: символы `sub` могут входить целиком в `origin` сохраняя последовательность. Могут входить и быть "разбросаны" по `origin`. Должно ли быть в `sub` и `origin` одинаковое число символов?  Из вопроса непонятно, какое именно вхождение требуется вам.

Comment: origin -Привет  sub- иве          .Должны сохранять последовательность .

Comment: Ещё, было бы не плохо, добавить некоторые проверки в начале метода if (Objects.equals(origin, sub) || Objects.equals(sub, "")) { return true; } if (sub.length() > origin.length()) { return false; }

Comment: Посмотреть исходники JDK и реализацию метода `String.contains()` :)

Comment: Что вы отсылаете человека к `String.contains` и спрашиваете "зачем"? Нормальное упражнение для начинающего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо наоборот:

```
for (int j = 0; j < two.length && i + j < one.length; j++) {
    if (two[j] == one[i + j]) {
```

Ну и неплохо бы обнулять `count` перед внутренним циклом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < two.length && i + j < one.length; j++) {
       if (two[j] == one[i + j])
           count++;
       else
           break;
    }
    if (count == two.length)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает)

Answer (score 0):

А так нельзя ?

```
public boolean contains(String origin, String sub) {

    if(origin.contains(sub)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Увы нет ) нужно именно через циклы

Comment: @Terasan зачем?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос.